# Why in iOS 11, my UIApplicationState show as inactive state instead of active?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, uiapplication

I have updated to latest xcode - 9 and iOS 11, now I am facing issue in UIApplicationState. Can anyone tell me why apple have done this changes in ApplicationState.

For instance:
   During viewController viewWillAppear, I am checking UIApplicationState:

```
     UIApplicationState applicationState = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState;
        if (applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
        {
        }
```

But I am getting applicationState = UIApplicationStateInactive.

Or do I need to handle separately for iOS 11 version by extra codes:

```
  if (applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive || (@available(iOS 11, *) && applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive)){
}
```

Any other answers to maintain application state consistently throughout all versions?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: same thing happens here

Comment: Did you consider subscribing to events from `NotificationCenter`? It allows to react as soon as the app changes its state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

** **UPDATED ANSWER** **

I used the following code to test states on both an iOS 10 and iOS 11 device.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("\(#function) active: \(UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active)")
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print("\(#function) active: \(UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active)")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print("\(#function) active: \(UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active)")

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
            print("\(#function) with delay active: \(UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active)")
        }
    }
}
```

When running on iOS 10:

```
viewDidLoad() active: false
viewWillAppear active: false
viewDidAppear active: true // This differs from 11
viewDidAppear with delay active: true
```

When running on iOS 11:

```
viewDidLoad() active: false
viewWillAppear active: false
viewDidAppear active: false
viewDidAppear with delay active: true
```

I can't tell you if this is intentional or not, but something has definitely changed. Perhaps file a radar on it?

Comment: I tried checking UIApplicationState in viewDidAppear, unlikely I am still getting "UIApplicationStateInactive" only instead of Active state.